# Is it possible to scan exchange(any) emails using .Net or Python

Tags: python, .net, security, spam-prevention, scanning

I'm curious to know that, is it possible to scan exchange or any other emails before performing any action(reading the body of the email, downloading the attachment, etc) on them.

Though scanning/email filtering/spam filtering is done at the network level(UTM), just I'm checking if we can do something at the programming level.

Please share your ideas on this. Thanks.

Comment: Does my post answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly. However,you can do some preliminary filtering searching with IMAP protocol (there are libaries in python for imap like `imaplib`). You can query for specific email(s), you can filter them out without ever downloading their contents just using handles or ids if you will.